# What language is that?

Tags: macos, programming-languages

Well I found a [nice tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/networking/conceptual/dns_discovery_api/Articles/registering.html) about how to program applications using Bonjour. It's cool. But the only problem, I do not understand which language they teach. I am not even sure that it is a programming language? May be they write about commands that should be typed in a command line? Or may be these are commands which should be executed in some GUI applications? Somehow I cannot find the context in which this tutorial is given. It is strange to me that they do not write what is that.

Can somebody resolve this mystery?

Comment: That is not a tutorial about how to program... That's the reference for some Mac OS X API...

Comment: I wonder how someone that asks something like this has 800+ rep...

Comment: 800 rep is nothing. I have 3K and I'm barely on the + side of clueless. What's really unexpected is this guy has multiple questions about Bonjour previously asked.

Comment: Well, I formulated that in a bad way. I know that it is about how to use Bonjour. But I could not figure out which language they are presenting. It is C. Or more precisely it is Bonjour API for C. Good. What about the command line? Can I use Bonjour from the command line?

Comment: Martinho Fernandes, I program for several years. I know Python, PHP, C++ and other stuff. I know object oriented programming. I have a Doctor Degree in natural sciences. But on that page I did not see what language is that! I saw "C" in the context on the left, but why should I assume that the current article was about C???

Comment: The trick is knowing just how clueless you really are. I tend to find that "smart" people are just more aware of their overall cluelessness.

Comment: Martinho Fernandes, you see, you made the same mistake. You told me that it is "MAC OS X API" but you did not told me about the language! And the answer was "C"!

Comment: @Mike Sherov: That's called the Dunning-Kruger effect. @Roman Bonjour is a network protocol. You cannot use it "directly" from the command-line. Typically you use a program that uses it behind the covers to do its thing, or you write such a program using the aforementioned API.

Comment: Martinho Fernandes, I thought that ZeroConf is a protocol and Bonjour is an application that implements the ZeroConf protocol. I do not understand why Bonjour can be used from a programming language (Java, Python, C) and at the same time it cannot be used from the command line. Why should it be hard to register a service from the command line. Why should it be impossible to type a command in the command line and get information about the available services.

Comment: Martinho Fernandes, the Dunning-Kruger effect is not relevant here. I do not overestimate my abilities and do not make some decisions. I just try to understand things and I am honest what I cannot understand trivial things (I dot not try to look smart, sometimes I ask stupid questions).

Comment: I'm sorry, you're totally right. ZeroConf is the name of the protocol, yes. Bonjour is the name of Apple's implementation of it. I'm sure you can do what you said in the command line. I didn't say it was *impossible*. I said you can use a program that uses that API to do it (I saw someone mention `mDNS` in the answers). I wasn't saying you're an example of Dunning-Kruger, I was just naming the phenomenon Mike mentioned (which I think is actually a good thing). I'm sorry if it came across as the wrong idea. Now, to avoid looking any more stupid that I did already, this is my last comment here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the left, there's a block that says:

```
RELATED REFERENCE 
PROCEDURAL C DNS
Service Discovery C Reference
```

I'm going to go out on a limb and say it's probably C.

Answer (score 8):

Its the C API for apple's Bonjour services; this is hardly a programming tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

That’s not a tutorial about how to program, OS X programs are written in Objective-C (although this is a C API), and that page has a table of contents on the left side.

The [`mDNS`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mDNS.1.html) command line tool can be used to test Bonjour services.

Comment: In addition to `mDNS` here is also the `dns-sd` utility: http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20051026183044858

Answer (score 2):

From the URL, title, and menu you can tell that it's a article about registering services using their dns_discovery_api in C.

This is not a programming tutorial.